# Has refactor rename has regressed in IntelliJ v14?

Tags: intellij-idea

Has the behaviour of renaming a variable in IntelliJ changed in v14.0.2?

I am used to pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> on a variable name, and IntelliJ giving me a number of excellent suggestions. For example, in the following example, if I clicked on `badName` and pressed <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd>, Intellij would make suggestions like `status` and `fooStatus` (and maybe even  more!).

```java
Map<String, Object> myMap = new HashMap<String, Object>;
FooStatus badName = (FooStatus) myMap.get("status");
```

But now it suggests nothing, and `badName` is the only item in the dropdown.

Comment: I tried it in 13 and 14 and I don't get the status and fooStatus suggestions. But when I type `(FooStatus) myMap.get("status")` and apply extract variable refactoring I get the expected suggestions in both 13 and 14. Strange ...

Answer (score 0):

I am using 14.0.2 and I have no such issues. Maybe it is because you don't have the `new` keyword for you `HashMap` ?

Comment: Woops, I've corrected that typo (although that was not my actual code in IntelliJ). Glad to see you are not having problems. I have tried Invalidate Caches, but it hasn't helped me.